# jQuery Toggle class with an ALL selector

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu and I need to toggle the class which is easy enough but I'm stuck on one feature i need to have... I will explain my issue:

I have this list menu `<li>`:

`[ALL][ITEM 1][ITEM 2][ITEM 3][ITEM 4][ITEM 5][ITEM 6]`

When I select any `[ITEM]` it toggles the class `itemSelect` and unselects `[ALL]` (be removing the class `itemSelect` from `[ALL]`)

If I select `[ALL]` it removes `itemSelect` from all apart from `[ALL]`

this is all I have so far:

```
$('.my-menu ul.menu li').click(function () {
     $(this).toggleClass("itemSelect");
});
```

if it helps here is the HTML:

```
<div class="my-menu">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="tagSelected"> <a rel="All" href="#">ALL</a></li>
    <li class=""> <a href="#" rel="1">ITEM 1</a> </li>
    <li class=""> <a href="#" rel="2">ITEM 2</a> </li>
    <li class=""> <a href="#" rel="3">ITEM 3</a> </li>
    <li class=""> <a href="#" rel="4">ITEM 4</a> </li>
    <li class=""> <a href="#" rel="5">ITEM 5</a> </li>
    <li class=""> <a href="#" rel="6">ITEM 6</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FWtQf/2/. I think this is what you are looking for.

Edit

updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FWtQf/3/

update again http://jsfiddle.net/FWtQf/4/

Comment: Looks great thanks.. one thing that I may not have been clear on. When I select ALL it should remove the class from all the other elements.

Comment: Here is another update. I've fix this issue and added console logs to show the results for you. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.my-menu ul.menu li').click(function () {
    if(this.rel === "All") {
        $('.my-menu ul.menu li').removeClass("itemSelect");
    }else{
        $(this).toggleClass("itemSelect");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<div class="my-menu">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="tagSelected all"> <a rel="All" href="#">ALL</a></li>
    <li class=""> <a href="#" rel="1">ITEM 1</a> </li>
    <li class=""> <a href="#" rel="2">ITEM 2</a> </li>
    <li class=""> <a href="#" rel="3">ITEM 3</a> </li>
    <li class=""> <a href="#" rel="4">ITEM 4</a> </li>
    <li class=""> <a href="#" rel="5">ITEM 5</a> </li>
    <li class=""> <a href="#" rel="6">ITEM 6</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>



$('.my-menu ul.menu li').click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('all')){
         $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('itemSelect');
         $(this).addClass("itemSelect");
    }
    else {
         $(this).siblings('li.all').removeClass('itemSelect');
         $(this).toggleClass("itemSelect");
    }
});
```